# Powershell, remove spaces between values

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, string-concatenation

When i export to a csv file, i get spaces on either side of a pipline that i need between two to diffrent values in the same cell. However i need to get rid of the spcaces before i import it to a system.

```
$DNs = @(
"OU=Personal,OU=Administration,OU=ccc,DC=aaa,DC=bbb,DC=se"
)

# Create empty array
$System_Users = @()

$Pipeline = "|";

# Loop through every DN
foreach ($DN in $DNs) {
$Users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $DN -Filter * -Properties *

# Add users to array
$System_Users += $Users
}

# Create list
$System_Users | Select-Object `
@{Label = "First name"; Expression = { $_.givenName } },
@{Label = "Last name"; Expression = { $_.sn } },
@{Label = "User logon name"; Expression = { $_.sAMAccountName } },
@{Label = "Job Title"; Expression = { $_.Title } },
@{Label = "Department"; Expression = { $_.department } },
@{Label = "Company"; Expression = { $_.company } },
@{Label = "Manager"; Expression = { % { (Get-AdUser $_.Manager -Properties cn).cn } } },
@{Label = "E-mail"; Expression = { $_.Mail } },
@{Label = "Groups"; Expression = {$_.company, $Pipeline, $_.department } },
@{Label = "Account status"; Expression = { if (($_.Enabled -eq 'TRUE') ) { 'Enabled' } Else
{'Disabled'} } } |


# Export report to CSV file
#Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -path $Csvfile -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ","
Export-Csv C:\Support\Script\System_Users\System_users_group.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "," -   Encoding UTF8
```

The result looks like this (note the space on either side of the `|` symbol in the field corresponding to the `Groups` property):

```
"First name","Last name",...,"E-mail","Company | Department","Account status"
```

So any ideas how to remove the space before and after the pipeline?

Comment: If you want to concatenate a string you can use `@{Label = "Groups"; Expression = { $_.company + '|' + $_.department } },` ... I just don't get why you name this property `Groups`.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!

It's because in the system it's being imported into, will use the two diffrent values to create groups, in the system one can only pick the value from one cell and we need both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_.company, $Pipeline, $_.department` creates an *array* (via [`,`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-), the comma operator), and when that array is implicitly *stringified* by [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv), its (stringified) elements are joined by a *space* as the separator.<sup>[1]</sup>

E.g., `[string] ('a', '|', 'c')` (as well as `"$('a', '|', 'c')"`) becomes `'a | c'`

To get the desired representation (e.g, `'a|b'`), you must perform the stringification yourself, and there are two basic options:

- As [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) notes, you can use *string concatenation* with `+`, the [addition / string concatenation operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arithmetic_Operators):

  ```bash
  # NOTE:
  #  The [string] cast is only needed if $_.company isn't already a string.
  [string] $_.company + $Pipeline + $_.department
  ```
- Especially if there are three or more elements to join, use `-join`, the [string joining operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join):

  ```bash
  # NOTE:
  #  No [string] cast needed - all elements are implicitly stringified as needed.
  $_.company, $_.department -join $Pipeline
  ```

---

<sup>[1] A space is the default separator; though it is rarely used (and best avoided), you can specify a different separator via the [`$OFS` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#ofs).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can remove one or more spaces around a character `|` as follows:

```
PS> $str -replace " *\| *", "|"
```

This means: Replace the pattern that matches the regex `" *\| *"` with `"|"`.

Comment: Don't you agree that it's better not to put unwanted spaces there in the first place than removing them afterwards? 

Comment: @Olaf I agree. This is yet another method.